# How to check null on StringBuilder?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I want to check for null or empty specifically in my code. Does empty and null are same for `StringBuilder` in Java?

For example:

```
StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder err= new StringBuilder(); 
success = executeCommand(cmd, state, err); 

/* here executeCommand() returns empty or null in state, I cant  make changes in  <br/> executeCommand() so can I check it in my code somehow for state, if its null or empty? */<br/>

if (state == null) { //do blabla1 }
if (state.tostring().equals("")) { //do blabla2 }
```

Does above code make sense or how should I change it?

Comment: It's not the same thing everywhere, not only `StringBuilder`.

Comment: If you run static analysis for your code it will complain that the code in the if(state == null) block will never be executed as "state" can never be null on that line (since it has been just initialized to a non-null value). That should give a pointer to null and "" being quite different things.

Comment: thx..i have missed one more line in my code..i will edit it and put some more details.

Comment: (since it has been just initialized to a non-null value).? where exactly it becoming non-null?

Comment: StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder(); this makes state non-null

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, `null` and `empty` are different for `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder nullBuilder = null;
if(nullBuilder == null) {
    System.out.println("Builder is null");
}
```

&

```
StringBuilder emptyBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
if(emptyBuilder == null || emptyBuilder.toString().equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Builder is empty");
}
```

Comment: does StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder()       and    StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder("")  are same??

Comment: This answer is wrong. The second example in it does not work because emptyBuilder i not null which makes the System.out.printLn statement dead code.

Comment: @Marquez The null check was completely unnecessary because the `StringBuilder` is defined in the previous statement. I submitted an edit to remove it, which should fix the check.

Comment: `emptyBuilder.toString().equals(""))` should be `emptyBuilder.toString().isEmpty())`

Comment: @user1145280 Yes, both are the same thing.

Answer (score 12):

In Java, `null` is a *reference literal*. If a variable is `null` then is not referring to anything.

So, if you have `StringBuilder s = null`, that means that `s` is of type `StringBuilder` but it is not referring to a `StringBuilder` instance.

If you have a non-`null` reference then you are free to call *methods* on the referred object. In the `StringBuilder` class, one such method is `length()`. In fact if you were to call `length()` using a `null` reference then the Java runtime will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Hence, this code is quite common:

```
If (s == null || s.length() == 0/*empty if the length is zero*/){
    // do something
```

It relies on the fact that evaluation of `||` is from left to right and stops once it reaches the first `true` condition.

Answer (score 5):

Null mean, there are no object in the heap for that reference variable. This is common to all java object, not specific to `StringBuilder` and Empty means, `""`.

In your code, you have created a StringBuilder object, so checking null is redundant. And, You can check empty by using `isEmpty()` method in from java String api

```
if(state.tostring().isEmpty()) {
//
}
```

And checking null is correct. Find the corrected version here

```
if (state == null) {
// ...bla 1
} else if (state.tostring().isEmpty()) {
//... bla 2
}
```

Your second `if` condition will throw `NullPointerException`, if the `state` is null. So `if` should be nested with `if else`

Answer (score 1):

No. `empty` means, that there are no characters in the StringBuilder. `null` means that there is no StringBuilder object at all.

A variable is only `null` if it has a reference type (for example String, StringBuilder, Set, as a thumbrule: all capitalized types) and it is not initialised yet or has been set explicitly to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you,

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String str = sb.toString();
if(!"".equals(str)) {
    System.out.println("String : " + str);
} else {
    System.out.println("Empty Builder");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder();
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(state .toString())){   
//this will check for null, " ", ""
}
```