# Check if StringBuffer is empty

Tags: java

Can anyone please tell me how I can use if-else condition with StringBuffer to check if it is empty?

I am expecting something like this

```
if (Stringbuffer is empty){ 
    // some condition 
}
else {
   // some other condition
}
```

Comment: [`StringBuffer.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#length()). But also you should be using `StringBuilder`, unless you require the extra synchronization (you almost certainly don't).

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21553582/4475997).

Comment: There's a thing called the Javadoc

Comment: StringBuffer was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments and has a supplied answer.

Answer (score 22):

[`StringBuffer.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#length()):

> [returns] the length of the sequence of characters currently represented by this object

so you can use the fact that `StringBuffer.length()` returns zero (or not) to check if the buffer is empty (or not).

---

Note that you should probably be using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `StringBuffer`. From the [Javadoc of `StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer buffer = null;

if(buffer == null || buffer.length() == 0){
     // some condition 
}else{
     // some other condition 
}
```

Comment: At least with Java 16, you don't need to check if the StringBuffer == null, that will always be false, even if the buffer is empty. Just doing `if(buffer.length() == 0){` is enough.